# Issue with Parent-Child Relationship in Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parent-child

Suppose I have two `tables` with parent-child relationship in `sql server` as below,

parent table:

```
Parentid  value 

1         demo
2         demo2
```

child table:

```
childid     parchildid   subvalue

1           1            demo1
2           1            demo2
```

here `parchildid` from `child table`  is a `foreign key` referring `parentid` of the `parent table`.

I needed to retrieve child table data for a particular parentid. So, I used below query

```
 select *from child
 where parchildid in (select parchildid from parent)
```

It gave the below output. ( all the rows for `child table`)

```
 childid    parchildid   subvalue

  1         1            demo1
  2         1            demo2
```

But as you see, I have given a `invalid` column (`parchildid`) in the sub-query ( `parchildid` belongs to `child table` not the `parent table` ).

I wonder why `sql server` didn't throw any error.

running `select parchildid from parent`
query alone thows `invalid` column error.

could anyone explains why there is no error thrown in the sub-query? hows the logic works there?

Thanks

Comment: There is no error because the columns from the main `SELECT` query can be referenced in the subquery. Basically, you're checking if the `childid = 1` is IN `1` which is always true, thus all rows from your `child` table shows.

Comment: Please look at doing this in a JOIN rather than in the where clause that you're currently doing it.

Comment: it is because you can use outer field in inner table so it is considered of child table field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equivalent to writing:

```
select *
  from child c
 where c.parchildid in 
     (
        select c.parchildid
          from parent p
     )
```

If you notice, `child` has an alias of `c` which is accessible inside the subquery.

It is also like writing:

```
select *
  from child c
 where Exists 
     (
        select *
          from parent p
         where c.parchildid = c.parchildid
     )
```

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx):

> If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query.

In your case, since `parchildid` is a column from the table in the outer query, there is no error. On it's own however, the query cannot find such a column, and so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

It gives only those records which have parent and child id same.

Answer (score 1):

Since your requirement is to retrieve **child table data for a particular parentid** Use the **parentid instead of parchildid**. Here since **parchildid** from child table is a foreign key referring **parentid** of parent table, there is no issue. Else it affect your result set . Please check the below code

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE
(Parentid int, Value varchar(10))

DECLARE @Child TABLE
(Childid int, parchildid int, subvalue varchar(10))

INSERT @Parent
(Parentid,[Value])
VALUES
(1,'demo'),(2,'demo2')

INSERT @Child
(Childid,parchildid,subvalue)
VALUES
(1,1,'demo'),(2,1,'demo2'),(3,3,'demo3')
```

Using parchildid

```
select * from @Child
where parchildid in (select parchildid from @Parent)
```

Output :

```
 Childid    parchildid  subvalue
 1          1           demo
 2          1           demo2
 3          3           demo3
```

Using Parentid

```
select * from @Child
where parchildid in (select Parentid from @Parent)
```

Output:

```
Childid parchildid  subvalue
 1          1           demo
 2          1           demo2
```

Comment: thanks but you cant have a value doesn't exists in parent table in child table is it?

Comment: You can't if you are using foreign key relationship. Else there can be. :)

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
 select * from child
 where parchildid in (select Parentid from parent)
```